# How to capture SQLCMD's Msg string using subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, sqlcmd

I am invoking sqlcmd via subprocess package. Though it is running fine, but i am unable to capture SQLCMD's failure messages and abort the deployment.

This is my code.

```
 try:
                            print(check_output(
                                'sqlcmd -S ' + args.serverName + ' -d ecomm -U ' + args.userName + ' -P ' + args.password + ' -i ' + fpath + '',
                                shell=True))
 except CalledProcessError as e:
                            print('Deployment of files has failed somehow. Please find below the bread crumbs...')
                            logging.info('Deployment of files has failed somehow. Please below the bread crumbs...')
                            print(e.output)
                            logging.info(e.output)
 finally:
                            print('Successfully deployed ' + fname + ' to the database')
                            logging.info('Successfully deployed ' + fname + ' to the database')
```

I am getting the below output.

```
Going ahead with deployment
Going to invoke sqlcmd cli to deploy dbo.uspFindProducts_SP.StoredProcedure.sql...
b"Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server IDEA-PC\\SQLEXPRESS, Procedure uspFindProducts_SP, Line 18\r\nIncorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.\r\n"
Successfully deployed dbo.uspFindProducts_SP.StoredProcedure.sql to the database
```

`Check_output` is printing `b"Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server IDEA-PC\\SQLEXPRESS, Procedure uspFindProducts_SP, Line 18\r\nIncorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.\r\n"`

Ideally, upon hitting `Msg` string it should enter exception block and abort deployment.

How can I capture `Msg` string so that whenever such string statement comes, the deployment would be aborted.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question guys...

I have resolved the above user story by using a combination of bytes to utf-8 decoding and `shlex.split()`.

If the list created by `shlex.split()` is not empty then abort the deployment.

```
sub = subprocess.run(["sqlcmd", "-S", .....], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
decoded_stdout = sub.stdout.decode('utf-8')
stdout_list = shlex.split(decoded_stdout)

if stdout_list != 0:
     print('Don't do the deployment')
else:
     print('do the deployment')
```

This is output and log.

```
2020-05-02 17:44:52,874:INFO:395:Going to invoke sqlcmd cli to deploy dbo.uspFindProducts_SP.StoredProcedure.sql...
2020-05-02 17:44:53,159:INFO:399:Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server IDEA-PC\SQLEXPRESS, Procedure uspFindProducts_SP, Line 18

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.


2020-05-02 17:44:53,159:INFO:403:Something failed and we have got a non-zero return code
```

Now the error is nicely decoded to utf-8 and the error string is split to a list using `shlex.split()`.
Have a good day everyone! :)